# Using Google's Colaboratory, are package installations necessary every time the document is opened?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am starting to try out [Google's Colaboratory](https://colab.research.google.com/notebook)  (it is very cool!) -- is it expected with this system that you'd re-install any packages each time you return to the doc / is there a known time-out I should expect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is the expected behavior.

Currently, each user gets assigned a new VM, and that VM is reclaimed when the user is idle for a given period. (That period is currently 90 minutes, but may change in the future.) A single user with multiple notebooks open will all share a single backend VM; no two users will ever be assigned to the same VM.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to have the startup scirpts encapsulated away from the notebook ,to make for more readable notebooks ( and for not having repeated content in multiple notebooks - something like the Azure NOtebook setup .sh scripts https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2017/09/20/installing-python-packages-to-azure-notebooks/

Comment: not right now - but feel free to file a feature request at github.com/googlecolab/colabtools.